# Save file in a sibling directory after creating a directoy

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, writefile

I'm having issues to write a file in a specific directory while calling fs.writeFile from nodejs.
It ends up creating the file in the same parent directory from where it is called.

```
function ensureDirectoryExists(filePath) {
  const dirname = path.dirname(filePath);
  if (fs.existsSync(dirname)) {
    return true;
  }
  ensureDirectoryExists(dirname);
  fs.mkdirSync(dirname);
}


function getFilePath(fileName, resultPath) {
  return path.join(resultPath, fileName);
}

export function writeDataToFile(fileName, resultPath) {
    fs.writeFile(getFilePath(fileName, resultPath), data, function (err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log('Error: ', err);
        }
        console.log('Saved successfully');
    });
}
```

So, my method writeDataToFile is called in my file - 'test.js'. So, I'm sending the resultPath to writeDataToFile from 'test.js' as -'parent/childDir/data/resultsDir'.
However, the file is being created at - 'parent/childDir/tests/testDir1'.

How could I fix this and create directory at run time before calling 'getFilePath()' using 'ensureDirectoryExists()' method?

Folder Structure:

[image]

Comment: In your function getFilePath what is filePath? And why are you calling ensureDirectoryExists recursively?

Comment: I corrected getFilePath() method now. I thought it was required to call it recursively in case of calling it asynchronously.

Comment: Your function is synchronous, if you want it to work also asynchronously you may want to work with Promises for example. Therefor now you should remove the second call.